# Indexing error after removing line from 2D array

Tags: python, for-loop, indexing

I am facing an **'List Index out of range'** error when trying to iterate a for-loop over a table I've created from a CSV extract, but cannot figure out why - even after trying many different methods.

Here is the step by step description of how the error happens :

1. I'm removing the first line of an imported CSV file, as this
   line contains the columns' names but no data. The CSV has the following structure.

```
columnName1, columnName2, columnName3, columnName4
This,        is,          some,        data
I,           have,        in,          this
very,        interesting, CSV,         file
```

2. After storing the CSV in a first array called oldArray, I want to populate a newArray that will get all values from oldArray but **not** the first line, which is the column name line, as previously
   mentioned. My newArray should then look like this.

```
This,        is,          some,        data
I,           have,        in,          this
very,        interesting, CSV,         file
```

3. To create this newArray, I'm using the following code with the append() function.

```
tempList = []
newArray = []
for i in range(len(oldArray)):
        if i > 0:   #my ugly way of skipping line 0...
                for j in range(len(oldArray[0])):
                        tempList.append(oldArray[i][j])
                newArray.append(tempList)
                tempList = []
```

- *I also stored the columns in their own separate list.*

```
i = 0
for i in range(len(oldArray[0])):
        my_columnList[i] =  oldArray[0][i]
```

4. And the error comes up next : I now want to populate a treeview table from this newArray, using a for-loop and insert (in a function). But I always get the 'Index List out of range error' and I cannot figure out why.

```
def populateTable(my_tree, newArray, my_columnList):
        i = 0        
        for i in range(len(newArray)):
                my_tree.insert('','end', text=newArray[i][0], values = (newArray[i][1:len(newArray[0]))
                #(im using the text option to bypass treeview's column 0 problem)
        return my_tree
```

**Error message --> " File "(...my working directory...)", line 301, in populateTable
my_tree.insert(parent='', index='end', text=data[i][0], values=(data[i][1:len(data[0])]))
IndexError: list index out of range "**

Using that same function with different datasets and columns worked fine, but not for this here newArray.

I'm fairy certain that the error comes strictly from this 'newArray' and is not linked to another parameter.

I've tested the validity of the columns list, of the CSV import in oldArray through some print() functions, and everything seems normal - values, row dimension, column dimension.

This is a great mystery to me...
Thank you all very much for your help and time.

Comment: Is it exact same code that you use? In number 4, value `values = (newArray[i][1:len(newArray[0]))` seems wrong. And it's better to write entire error message.

Comment: Hi, this is indeed the same code I'm using - as for the values = (newArray[i][1 : len(newArray[0]), I can confirm that this works : I've tried it on other tables and it worked with no problem. It's only this 'newArray' here that causes trouble.

The entire error message is :
 " File "(...my working directory...)", line 301, in populateTable
    my_tree.insert(parent='', index='end', text=data[i][0], values=(data[i][1:len(data[0])]))
IndexError: list index out of range "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a problem from your error message: `File "(...my working directory...)", line 301, in populateTable my_tree.insert(parent='', index='end', text=data[i][0], values=(data[i][1:len(data[0])])) IndexError: list index out of range`

It means there is an index out of range in line 301: `data[i][0]` or `data[i][1:len(data[0])]`

(`i` is over `len(data)`) or (`0` or `1` is over `len(data[0])`)

My guess is there is some empty list in data(maybe `data[-1]`?).

if `data[i]` is [] or [some_one_item], then `data[i][1:len(data[0])]` try to access to second item which not exists.

Comment: Thanks for replying  ! you've pointed out that my data array has indeed *no* dimension at all - 
Following your msg, I've tried the following test values, all returning a List Index error :
test0 = newArray[0][0] ; test1 = newArray[-1][0] ; test2 = newArray[-2][0] ; test3 = newArray[0][1].
I'm wondering how this is even possible ?... (error example below)
test1 = insightsData[0][0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @tka2021 Does `oldArray` has value? print `len(oldArray)` and `len(newArray)`

Comment: Just tried this : oldArray does have values, eg oldArray[0][0] == columnName1 ; oldArray[1][0] == This. About lengths : len(oldArray) == 4 as expected, but len(newArray) == 0. Maybe this means that my line of code with append() is not working ?

Comment: If you don't have specific reason to make new list, then how about using `oldArray[0]` and `oldArray[1:]` instead `my_columnList` and `newArray`?

Comment: And in `populateTree`, `my_columnList` is not used. `my_tree.insert('','end', text=newArray[i][0], values = (newArray[i][1:len(newArray[0]))` is right? or `my_tree.insert('','end', text=my_columnList[i], values = (newArray[i]))` ?

Comment: A simple idea.... and you were right ! I overthought this when I wrote the code, your answer works ! No more indexing error now, my treeview table populates without problem now ! (the rows are repeating themselves, but that's just a minor issue in regards to my post). 
Thank you very much for your help !!!

Answer (score 0):

there is no problem in your "ugly" way to skip line 0 but I recommend having a look on this way

```
new_array = old_array.copy()
new_array.remove(new_array[0])
```

now for fixing your issue
looks like you have a problem in the indexing
when you use a for loop using the range of the length of an array you use normal indexing which starts from one while you identify your i variable to be zero

to make it simple

```
len(oldArray[0])
```

this is equal to 4 so when you use it in the for loop it's just like saying

```
for i in range(4):
```

to fix this you can either subtract 1 from the length of the old array or just identify the i variable to be 1 at the first

```
i = 1
for i in range(len(oldArray[0])):
    my_columnList[i] =  oldArray[0][i]
```

or

```
i = 0
for i in range(len(oldArray[0])-1):
    my_columnList[i] =  oldArray[0][i]
```

this mistake is also repeated in your populateTree function
so in the same way your code would be

```
def populateTree(my_tree, newArray, my_columnList):
    i = 0        
    for i in range(len(newArray)-1):
            my_tree.insert('','end', text=newArray[i][0], values = (newArray[i][1:len(newArray[0]))
            #(im using the text option to bypass treeview's column 0 problem)
    return my_tree
```

Comment: Hi Ahmed, thanks for the tip for the copy/remove line, I'll be sure to try it out ! I did some more research on my problem thanks to Canasta's answer, and it seems that my newArray has... no dimension at all ? just typing test1 = newArray[0][0] returns an 'Index Error' as well... I don't even know how this can happen, given my previous code...